# C# Dictionary of Objects

Tags: c#, data-structures

What is the best data structure for the following: I have a custom object

```
public class Package
{
   private Guid packageId;
   private List<Guid> contracts;
   private List<Guid> states;
   public List<Guid>Contracts {get;set;}
   public List<Guid>States {get;set;}
   public Guid PackageId { get; set; }
   public Package()
   {
    ....
   }
}
```

I will have a `List<Packages>` that contain and properties that share a common ID (PackageId). I will be adding guids to different properties (state, contract, etc) within the Package Objects at runtime (not all at init). How can I best structure the class to allow me to add various properties of the object after it has been initialized? 
Example, structure so that I can execute the following:

```
var List<Package> Packages = new List<Package>;
Packages[aGuid].Contracts.Add(Guid);
```

Comment: `somePackage.Contracts.Add(someGuid)`? It's a bit unclear what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: added a code sample, does that help?

Comment: You are probably looking for a dictionary if you want to use `Packages[aGuid]`...

Comment: If you can post a brief example I will select as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use that structure, you should use a `Dictionary<Guid, Package>`:

```
public class Package
{
   private Guid packageId;
   private List<Guid> contracts;
   private List<Guid> states;
   public List<Guid>Contracts {get;set;}
   public List<Guid>States {get;set;}
   public Guid PackageId { get; set; }
   public Package()
   {
       //Remember to initialize your List<T>'s here
   }
}
```

Create a `Dictionary`:

```
var packages = new Dictionary<Guid, Package>();
```

You then create a new package:

```
var package = new Package();
```

Add it to the dictionary:

```
packages[package.PackageId] = package;
```

-or-

```
packages.Add(package.PackageId, package);
```

The difference between the two above is that the `.Add` will throw an exception if there is already an existing `PackageId` whereas the `[]` version will just overwrite it.

And now you can access it like you desire:

```
packages[SomePackageId].Contracts.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
```

Comment: Looks good. Any opinions as to whether the dictionary will be the best approach here?

Comment: "Best" is really a matter of opinion. `Dictionary` will do what you want, is a fast key/value store, and is relatively universal. For what it looks like you are using it for (without more context), this is probably the *simplest* and easiest option, which is a good thing in software development.